# Identity for categorical product is terminal?

Tags: category-theory

It is well-known that for a category $\mathbf{C}$ with *binary* products and terminal object $\mathbf{1} \in \mathbf{C}$, we have $\mathbf{1} \times A \cong A$ naturally in $A$. I want to know if the converse holds, i.e. if $B \times A \cong A$ for all objects $A$, does this mean $B$ is terminal?

Comment: what happens if you take $A$ to be the terminal object?

Comment: That's assuming *a priori* that there *is* a terminal object, which I didn't mean to do. I've edited the question.

Comment: It's not the converse if you don't ask for the isomorphism to be natural in $A$! (Really the "true" converse would be to ask for the projection $\pi_A : B \times A \to A$ to be an isomorphism and then the answer is affirmative as Berci says, since this is the sense in which we have $1 \times A \cong A$; it's not just a natural isomorphism, it's the projection.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer is no. Consider for instance $\mathbf{C}$ the full subcategory of $\mathbf{Ab}$ (the category of abelian groups) consisting of only the single object $\mathbb{Z}^\mathbb{N}$. Now, $\mathbb{Z}^\mathbb{N}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{Z}^\mathbb{N}$ in $\mathbf{Ab}$, and we can exploit this fact to show that $\mathbf{C}$ is closed under binary products. To see this, define projection maps $\pi_1,\pi_2:\mathbb{Z}^\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{Z}^\mathbb{N}$ by
\begin{align}
\pi_1(x_0,x_1,\dots)&= (x_0,x_2,x_4,\dots)\\
\pi_2(x_0,x_1,\dots)&= (x_1,x_3,x_5,\dots).
\end{align}
I'll leave it to you to show that this indeed induces a product structure on $\mathbb{Z}^\mathbb{N}$. In particular, your desired condition holds for $B=\mathbb{Z}^\mathbb{N}$ in $\mathbf{C}$, but $\mathbb{Z}^\mathbb{N}$ is certainly not a terminal object in $\mathbf{C}$; it has many non-identity endomorphisms.

Comment: Note that this map $B\times A\to A$ is *not a natural transformation* in the second variable.

Comment: @Berci indeed, a good point! :) (+1 on your answer)

Comment: Actually, I wanted to prove the intermediate statement with the condition $B\times A\cong A$ naturally in $A$, but probably it still fails.

Comment: No, it does hold! Added into my answer.

Comment: @Berci right on, nice argument!!

Answer (score 10):

If we strengthen the condition, we can get an affirmative answer.

Namely, first assume that specifically the second projection $\pi_2:B\times A\to A$ is invertible for all objects $A$ (implying that the isomorphism is natural in $A$).

Then we can conclude that $B$ is a terminal object:

For any object $A$ we have an arrow $A\overset{\pi_2^{-1}}\to B\times A\overset{\pi_1}\to B$, and this is unique, since for any $f:A\to B$, the arrow $(f,1_A):A\to B\times A$ is a right inverse of $\pi_2$, as $\pi_2\circ(f,1_A)=1_A$, hence it is its inverse now, and thus
$$f=\pi_1\circ (f,1_A)=\pi_1\circ\pi_2^{-1}\,.$$

---

Secondly, if we only have a natural isomorphism $\tau_A:A\to B\times A$, the conclusion still holds:

Let $\alpha_A:=\pi_2\circ\tau_A:A\to A$, this is still natural in $A$, and consider $u:=\tau_A^{-1}\circ (f,1_A):A\to A$ with an arbitrary $f:A\to B\ $ (say, $f=\pi_1\circ\tau_A$), then by naturality of $\alpha:{\rm id}_{\bf C}\to{\rm id}_{\bf C}$, we obtain
$$\alpha_A\circ u = u\circ\alpha_A$$
where we have $\alpha_A\circ u=\pi_2\circ (f,1_A)=1_A$, so $\alpha_A$ and hence also $\pi_2$ is invertible, and $(f,1_A)=\pi_2^{-1}$ with every $f$, showing its uniqueness as above.